# Jupyter notebookでデフォルトディレクトリ以外でファイルを作成できない

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, file

Windows10でJupyter notebookを使用しています。
1. homeページで[New]からノートを作成する > 作成できる。セーブもできる。動作も正常。
2. homeページで別のディレクトリを選択し、そこで[New]からノートを作成すると、エラーが発生する。

> Unexpected error while saving file: Documents/python/Untitled1.ipynb [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\[user_name]\\Documents\\python\\Untitled1.ipynb'

jupyter_notebook_config.pyでデフォルトディレクトリを設定しても同様でした。また、jupyter notebookを管理者権限で起動しても同様でした。カレントディレクトリとなっていることも確認しています。

上記エラーメッセージで2つディレクトリ表現があるのですが、一方がスラッシュで、もう一方がバックスラッシュ2つになっているのが、なんとなく気になります。

原因または解決法のわかる方、お教えいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 別のディレクトリからnotebookを作成しても普通はエラーにならないので、質問の内容だけだと情報が少なすぎて原因はわからないと思います。できれば、ログを省略しないで提示するか、python, Jupyter notebook のバージョン等を細かく記載してもらえると原因がわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: C:\直下に作成しようとするとどうなりますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。問題はwindows defenderの設定にありました。保護されたフォルダ以下で、許可されていないアプリによるファイルセーブなどができないということでした。お騒がせしました。